FFmpeg H.264 NVENC - high444p profile not working at 1920x1080 via library but works via command line encoding
I am building a real-time desktop streaming application in Rust and I am using FFmpeg (H.264 NVENC) to encode the raw frames captured as BGRA from desktop.
I am able to get it to work on profiles such as baseline, main, and high but nothing seems to be working on high444p which is what I need to do 4:4:4 chroma subsampling.
Below is the setup I have for constructing the encoder. I am using the rust-ac-ffmpeg crate to do this.
builder = builder
    .pixel_format("bgra")
    .height(1080)
    .width(1920)
    .set_option("profile", "high444p")
    .set_option("preset", "medium")
    .set_option("tune", "hq")
    .set_option("b:v", "30M")
    .set_option("maxrate", "30M")
    .set_option("bufsize", "60M")
    .set_option("framerate", "60")
    .set_option("pix_fmt", "yuv444p");

No matter what combination of settings I try, I always get a single line error as follows:
[h264_nvenc @ 0000020bf69f6680] InitializeEncoder failed: invalid param (8): Invalid Level.

I have also tried adding levels explicitly. Have tried 4.1, 4.2, 5.1, 5.2, 6.1 and 6.2.
The only case where this does work is if the resolution is low, let's say around 500x500 or 600x800. But this is not suitable for my usecases.
Moreover, the equivalent command for this just works right out of the box. On the same machine. Same ffmpeg version. Running this command on an output.raw file which is just a dump of the frames captured by my screen capture mechanism.
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -s 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -i input.raw -c:v h264_nvenc -preset p1 -profile:v high444p -pix_fmt yuv444p -b:v 30M -maxrate 30M -bufsize 60M output.mp4


You didn't include any versions and build flags for the FFMPEG library or command line tool.
You have proven that FFMPEG is capable of doing the right thing.
I am guessing that your FFMPEG library built may not contain the same code as the command line. But you didn't provide any versions or build flags.
I would build a debug version of the FFMPEG library and then debug it with a debugger.
